# Nelmio Apidocbundle. Properties from mapped superclass

Tags: symfony, doctrine, jmsserializerbundle

I have a Entity A which extends from Entity B. Entity B is a @ORM\MappedSuperclass.
In my controller I have following apidoc annotation:

```
/**
 * Gets a A by its identifier
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  resource=true,
 *  description="Gets a A by its identifier",
 *  tags={"stable"},
 *  https=true,
 *  output="Vendor\Bundle\VendorBundle\Entity\A",
 *  statusCodes={
 *      200="Returned when successful.",
 *      404="Returned when A with given identifier does not exist."
 *  }
 *
 * )
 *
 *
 * @param string $identifier The A's identifier
 * @throws \Vendor\Exception\ANotFoundException
 * @return JsonResponse
 *
 * @Route("/a/{identifier}")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
```

The resulting apidoc return section for the method GET will have all propierties from Entity A, but none from the mapped superclass Entity B.

Is there a way to also include the properties from the mapped superclass?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind. I found the solution.
the nelmio/api-doc-bundle requires that the mapped superclass has validation constraints annotations on its properties.

This WILL NOT work:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Util\Inflector;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
```

And this WILL WORK:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Util\Inflector;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $id;
```